# Kubernetes TLS secrets renewal with Godaddy renewed SSL certificates

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, godaddy-api

Is there a way to automate TLS secret renewal for Godaddy managed SSL certificates.
I want the Kubernetes TLS secret (which holds the wildcard certificate and key) to be renewed when the SSL certificate is renewed automatically in Godaddy (every 6/12 months).
Has anybody automated this process?

Cert-Manager doesn't seem to support Godaddy out of the box.

Comment: There is no reason to renew a key pair that hasn't been compromised, if that's what you're asking. If it isn't, please clarify.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.